# Getting different result in different runs with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

why when the code executed, the result different every time?

i tried to follow how the code is executed, and i confused, i feel this is not sense.

and the result appear randomly every time

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Queue
import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.q = q
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        process_data(self.name, self.q)
        print "Exiting " + self.name

def process_data(threadName, q):
    while not exitFlag:
        queueLock.acquire()
        if not workQueue.empty():
            data = q.get()
            queueLock.release()
            print "%s processing %s" % (threadName, data)
        else:
            queueLock.release()
        time.sleep(1)

threadList = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
queueLock = threading.Lock()
workQueue = Queue.Queue(10)
threads = []
threadID = 1

# Create new threads
for tName in threadList:
    thread = myThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    threadID += 1

# Fill the queue
queueLock.acquire()
for word in nameList:
    workQueue.put(word)
queueLock.release()

# Wait for queue to empty
while not workQueue.empty():
    pass

# Notify threads it's time to exit
exitFlag = 1

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

code source
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

---

**update**

Sorry, i mean the order of result

like this:

```
Starting Thread-1
Starting Thread-2
Starting Thread-3
Thread-3 processing One
Thread-2 processing Two
Thread-1 processing Three
Thread-3 processing Four
Thread-2 processing Five
Exiting Thread-1
Exiting Thread-3
Exiting Thread-2
Exiting Main Thread
[Finished in 3.0s]
```

and when try again, the result

```
Starting Thread-1
Starting Thread-2
Starting Thread-3
Thread-3 processing One
Thread-2 processing Two
Thread-1 processing Three
Thread-3 processing Four
Thread-3 processing Five
Exiting Thread-1
Exiting Thread-2
Exiting Thread-3
Exiting Main Thread
[Finished in 3.0s]
```

Comment: You say the result is different. What is the result? I can't see process_data actually doing anything, except a `print`.

Comment: the question updated.

Comment: The only difference there is that "Five" is processed by thread 3 instead of thread 2. That is not an actual difference in output. Which thread handles which part of the queue should not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, by "result" you mean the execution order. 
One idea behind mutithreading is, that you don't have to care about execution order unless you want to specify it explicitely. You are totally dependent on the underlying operating system, system load, ... etc.